# create plugin in wordpress with nodejs

Tags: node.js, wordpress, plugins

how are you? I would like to ask you if it is possible to create a wordpress plugin with nodejs, leaving aside php, I would understand that it is possible but I would like to know if anyone has had experience with this topic.
Can you tell me where to start?

Answer (score 0):

While NodeJS is purely javascript and a Wordpress plugin is a mainly PHP with added HTML, CSS and JS, as needed. The best option is to create a UI which generates the PHP stub code for a Wordpress plugin. I created a Wordpress Theme generator using Node-Electron which will create a simple Wordpress theme from a minimal set of metadata at https://sourceforge.net/projects/php-desktop-2020/files/